# Installing Apache Spark on linux

Tags: apache-spark

I am installing Apache Spark on linux. I already have Java, Scala and Spark downloaded and they are all in the Downloads folder inside the Home folder with the path /home/alex/Downloads/X where X=scala, java, spark, literally that's what the folders are called.

I got scala to work but when I try to run spark by typing ./bin/spark-shell it says:

```
/home/alex/Downloads/spark/bin/saprk-class: line 100: /usr/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
```

I have already included the file path by editing the bashrc with sudo gedit ~/.bashrc:

```
# JAVA
export JAVA_HOME=/home/alex/Downloads/java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

# scala
export SCALA_HOME=/home/alex/Downloads/scala
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin

# spark
export SPARK_HOME=/home/alex/Downloads/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
```

When I try to type sbt/sbt package in the spark folder it say no such file or directory is found also. What should I do from here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a few issues, namely your JAVA_HOME is not pointed to a directory with java, when you are running sbt in spark you should run `./sbt/sbt` (or in new versions `./build/sbt`). While you can download Java & Scala by hand, you may find that your system packages are sufficient (make sure to get jdk 7 or later).

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, after using  system packages as Holden points out, in Linux you may use the command [whereis](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Whereis) to make sure of the right paths.

Finally, the following link may prove useful:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/apache_spark_installation.htm
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note: It looks like there may be a configuration issue, misspelling, of the directory name

```
/home/alex/Downloads/spark/bin/saprk-class: line 100: /usr/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
```

> saprk-class

That could be a configuration issue only, but it's worth a look if it is called /spark-class elsewhere to see if it's causing related issues.